# Android PendingIntent in Notification from lock screen has different behavior than drawer

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have followed the documentation here to implement a PendingIntent to an Activity that has a parent:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html

Example: Activity A is the launcher activity, Activity B is another activity that's parent is Activity A.
The app creates a notification with a PendingIntent to Activity B. When you are on Activity B and press back, it should take you to Activity A.

This works fine when tapping the notification when the screen is unlocked. First Activity B is created, and when you press back, Activity A will be created under it.

However, when tapping the notification when the screen is locked there is different behavior: Activity A is created, and then Activity B is created.

I have noticed this in Android 7, haven't yet tried other versions.

Does this behavior make sense? The issue I am having is that Activity A has all sorts of special logic in onCreate, so if it gets launched first it causes issues for Activity B. I didn't notice this at first, because the whole flow works fine when the phone is unlocked!

Comment: Facing an issue on similar lines. Did 
you get a solution for this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056911/opening-notification-from-lock-screen-is-behaving-differently-than-opening-the-n